How can I make OFF as default settings for my VsCode Auto Save?
I want to make OFF as my default auto save settings. How can I do that ?
I tried searching over the internet but didn't found any answer for that. I have VsCode installed on other systems there I have OFF as default. Can somebody help me with this ?


Just uncheck the auto-save option in File -> Auto Save:


Hey, this does not solve my Problem. After removing that tick, it sets to OFF but only for some time. Then again it gets reverted to afterDelay...

Make sure in setting you have turned OFF the auto save, and it should work as you expect in all scenarios. I tried it after restarting the system as well. It was OFF only. If that default word after, after delay is making you doubt, then it shouldn't like in my system auto save is set to OFF on default, but as i checked auto save it always saves my content !!
